# Mole fraction of solute of a dilute solution

Tags: solutions

According to our book, when the solution is dilute, the mole fraction of solute can be given as:

X2 = molality (m) x mass of solvent (M1) / 1000

Actually it is written as:

X2 = m/(1000/M1)

How is this true?

The only reason i can think of is that as the solution is dilute, X2 should almost be equal to zero. As the solution is dilute so, molality is very low and it is also divided by 1000 which will give us a value near to zero (for X2). But i know its a poor explanation. So, how does this equation work?

Answer (score 2):

The formula is correct, being M1 the **molar** mass of the solvent. I'll call it below $ M_{solvent} $.

Starting from the definition of molar fraction:

$ X = \frac{mol_{solute}}{mol_{solvent}+mol_{solute}} $

For diluted solutions, we can simply write:

$ X = \frac{mol_{solute}}{mol_{solvent}} $

To introduce molality into the defintion of molar fraction, one has to consider the following:

$ mol_{solvent} = \frac{g_{solvent}}{g_{solvent}/mol_{solvent}}=\frac{g_{solvent}}{M_{solvent}} = \frac{kg_{solvent}}{M_{solvent}}1000$

Replacing the latter into the definition of molar fraction, you get:

$ X = \frac{mol_{solute}M_{solvent}}{kg_{solvent}1000} $

Considering that $mol_{solute}/kg_{solvent}$ is the molality $m$, you get your formula:

$X= \frac{mM_{solvent}}{1000} $

Comment: to convert g(solvent) into KG(solvent), you have multiplied g(solvent) by 1000. shouldn't it be divided?

Comment: I haven't done any conversion: in the definition of mole, mass must be expressed in grams. The use of kg is further imposed by the definition of molality. So, if you have $mol_{water}$=1 that means that you have 18 g of water or 0.018 kg * 1000 g/kg (notice that this last product still gives you **grams**).